# How to get grouped x-label with curly brace exactly align with the axis co-ordinates?

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, axis, tikz-graphdrawing

How to get the grouped labels with curly braces exactly in concurrence with the tikz axis, I could mange to align with arbitrarily value, is there any other way to align automatically?. For example, Task 1, Crew 1, the actual position is (0,0) to (3,0) but when drawn using the same, it does not produce the intended result, and hence draw, (0,0) to (4,0) to achieve the required result. Is there any automated procedure to fix this error, so that the arbitrary values may avoided.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title={},ylabel={\textbf{Task 2}},ymin=0,ymax=10,ytick={1, 2,...,10}, unbounded 
coords=jump, xmin=0,xmax=10,xtick={0,1,2,...,10},xlabel={\textbf{Task 1}},width=15.0cm,height=15.0cm,ylabel shift=0.75cm,xlabel shift=1.0cm,enlargelimits =false,grid,clip=false]
 \addplot+[thin,color=red,fill=red,mark=none]
 coordinates{
 (0,0)
 (3,0)
 (3,4)
 (0,4)
 (0,0)
 };
 \end{axis} 
 \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=7pt,mirror,raise=4ex},thick]
 (0,0) -- (4,0) node[midway,yshift=-3em]{\textbf{Crew 1}};
 \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=7pt,mirror,raise=4ex},thick]
 (4,0) -- (9.45,0) node[midway,yshift=-3em]{\textbf{Crew 2}};
 \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=7pt,mirror,raise=4ex},thick]
  (9.45,0) -- (13.5,0) node[midway,yshift=-3em]{\textbf{Crew 3}};
  \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=7pt,mirror,raise=4ex},thick,xshift=0.15em]
  (0,5.38) -- (0,0) node[midway,yshift=0em,xshift=-3em,rotate=90]{\textbf{Crew 1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give the ticks names via `alias`, and use these nodes to have the precise positions to draw the braces from outside (without dropping `clip` etc). It also makes sense to use styles for the repeating set of keys used for the braces.

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mbrace/.style={decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=7pt,mirror,raise=4ex},thick}]
\begin{axis}[title={},width=15.0cm,height=15.0cm,
    ylabel={\textbf{Task 2}},ymin=0,ymax=10,
    ytick={1, 2,...,10},yticklabel style={alias={ytick-\ticknum}}, 
    unbounded coords=jump, xmin=0,xmax=10,
    xtick={0,1,2,...,10},xticklabel style={alias={xtick-\ticknum}},
    xlabel={\textbf{Task 1}},ylabel shift=0.75cm,xlabel shift=1.0cm,
    enlargelimits =false,grid,clip=false]
 \addplot+[thin,color=red,fill=red,mark=none]
 coordinates{
 (0,0)
 (3,0)
 (3,4)
 (0,4)
 (0,0)
 };
 \end{axis} 
 \path (0,0) coordinate (P);
 \draw [mbrace] (xtick-0|-P) -- (xtick-3|-P) 
    node[midway,yshift=-3em,font=\bfseries]{Crew 1};
 \draw [mbrace] (xtick-3|-P) -- (xtick-6|-P) 
    node[midway,yshift=-3em,font=\bfseries]{Crew 2};
 \draw [mbrace] (xtick-6|-P) --(xtick-9|-P) 
    node[midway,yshift=-3em,font=\bfseries]{Crew 3};
 \draw [mbrace]  (ytick-3-|P) -- (current axis.south-|P) 
    node[midway,yshift=0em,xshift=-3em,rotate=90,font=\bfseries]{Crew 1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some users prefer calligraphic braces.

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mbrace/.style={decorate,decoration={calligraphic brace,amplitude=7pt,mirror,raise=4ex},thick}]
\begin{axis}[title={},width=15.0cm,height=15.0cm,
    ylabel={\textbf{Task 2}},ymin=0,ymax=10,
    ytick={1, 2,...,10},yticklabel style={alias={ytick-\ticknum}}, 
    unbounded coords=jump, xmin=0,xmax=10,
    xtick={0,1,2,...,10},xticklabel style={alias={xtick-\ticknum}},
    xlabel={\textbf{Task 1}},ylabel shift=0.75cm,xlabel shift=1.0cm,
    enlargelimits =false,grid,clip=false]
 \addplot+[thin,color=red,fill=red,mark=none]
 coordinates{
 (0,0)
 (3,0)
 (3,4)
 (0,4)
 (0,0)
 };
 \end{axis} 
 \path (0,0) coordinate (P);
 \draw [mbrace] (xtick-0|-P) -- (xtick-3|-P) 
    node[midway,yshift=-3em,font=\bfseries]{Crew 1};
 \draw [mbrace] (xtick-3|-P) -- (xtick-6|-P) 
    node[midway,yshift=-3em,font=\bfseries]{Crew 2};
 \draw [mbrace] (xtick-6|-P) --(xtick-9|-P) 
    node[midway,yshift=-3em,font=\bfseries]{Crew 3};
 \draw [mbrace]  (ytick-3-|P) -- (current axis.south-|P) 
    node[midway,yshift=0em,xshift=-3em,rotate=90,font=\bfseries]{Crew 1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Schrödinger's cat, this works perfect. Thank you very much for your kindness and support.

Comment: @RameshKannan You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the `axis cs` for the braces, draw them inside the `axis` environment:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads tikz, pgf, ...
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}% current version would be 1.17
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[title={},ylabel={\textbf{Task 2}},ymin=0,ymax=10,ytick={1, 2,...,10}, unbounded 
coords=jump, xmin=0,xmax=10,xtick={0,1,2,...,10},xlabel={\textbf{Task 1}},width=15.0cm,height=15.0cm,ylabel shift=0.75cm,xlabel shift=1.0cm,enlargelimits =false,grid,clip=false]
    \addplot+[thin,color=red,fill=red,mark=none]
      coordinates{ (0,0) (3,0) (3,4) (0,4) (0,0) };
    \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=7pt,mirror,raise=4ex},thick]
      (0,0) -- (3,0) node[midway,yshift=-3em]{\textbf{Crew 1}};
    \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=7pt,mirror,raise=4ex},thick]
      (3,0) -- (7,0) node[midway,yshift=-3em]{\textbf{Crew 2}};
    \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=7pt,mirror,raise=4ex},thick]
      (7,0) -- (10,0) node[midway,yshift=-3em]{\textbf{Crew 3}};
    \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=7pt,mirror,raise=4ex},thick,xshift=0.15em]
      (0,4) -- (0,0) node[midway,xshift=-3em,rotate=90]{\textbf{Crew 1}};
  \end{axis}% <- moved
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank for your suggestion. It works perfectly good.